# Use of perceptron for classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-science, perceptron

I am learning a concept of perceptron in machine learning and how it is used for classification. I know perceptron can classify data which is linearly separable and which is having boolean classification. But what is there are more than two classes are available for data and I need to built a model using that data. Is it possible to use perceptron in that case ?

Comment: [Read this for example](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65543/how-can-a-multiclass-perceptron-work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea in multiclass variant of the Perceptron algorithm is pretty much the
same as in the binary classification except for a few minor differences. In the
multiclass classification with *K* classes, we will maintain a set of *K* weight
vectors `W_{1},...,W_{K}` (each weight vector is of size D where D is the number
of features).

The prediction (both at training and test time) would change to:

```
\widehat{y}_{n} = arg max_{k}(W_{k}^{T} x_{n} + b)
```

which means that the predicted class will be the one for which the weight vector gives the highest score. The update condition is given by (assuming that yn is the true label of xn):

```
if(\widehat{y}_{n} != y_{n})
    W_{\widehat{y}_{n}} = W_{\widehat{y}_{n}} - X_{n}
    W_{\widehat{y}_{n}} = W_{\widehat{y}_{n}} + X_{n}
```